# Converting string into exception

Tags: c#, exception

I want to convert a string into exception but not able to find any thing on google.

I am using C# .Net 2.0.

Reason is because third party client has a method that is logging method and only takes exception and i have a scenario where i must need to log something but using that method. so must need to convert string into exception.

Comment: This should have popped up very, very easily on Google: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx

Comment: what keywords should i had used to search it ?

Comment: I searched for [exception string C#]. The `Exception` constructor was the second result returned.

Comment: I tried "convert string to exception c#" and nothing related came up, thanks anyway

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Exceptions are created as any other object, using the `new` keyword. You can provide it a message argument that you can store your string in:

```
Exception e = new Exception("Your string goes here");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Try...Catch() then you can do following to add your customize message and original exception together

```
try{
    //your code block
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    var exception = new Exception("Your message: ");
    //Display "exception" to users
    //Log "e" for further investigation 
}
```